# Next js throws unexpected document not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am learning **next.js** and while working on a project I got this **error**.

I am using a module named Typed.js here
It says *Server Error
ReferenceError: document is not defined*

*This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.*

And tells that the problem is in this code.

When I comment out this code then website works fine and even if I remove the comment while the website is running then it works find. It only shows this when website is reloaded or refreshed completely.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiFt7.png)

[Link to the index.js file](https://github.com/Atharv-coder1005/error-app)

````
//typing text animation script
var typed = new Typed(".typing", {
     strings: ["Developer", "Designer"],
     typeSpeed: 100,
     backSpeed: 60,
     loop: true
});

 var typed = new Typed(".typing-2", {
     strings: ["Game", "Graphic"],
     typeSpeed: 100,
     backSpeed: 60,
     loop: true
 });```
````

Comment: Try adding the code of the component. This question is incomplete and it would be very difficult to answer. Also. Try to put links outside of code scope to be able to be clicked instead of having to copy and paste to see ur error. Also remember NextJS is server side rendered and you don't have access to the window object. So your error might be related to the package trying to access the window.document.

Comment: Sir this is the only code which creates error, I reinstalled nodejs and created s new next app in it. I tried to run only this code now but it gives same error. Here is the link to index.js file https://github.com/Atharv-coder1005/error-app

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) into a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the script is called before the `document` or DOM content is loaded. I think you might want to check first if window is not undefined before initializing the Typed class, check below link  for reference:

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined

Comment: when I try this code it gives me error if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('You are on the browser')
  const elem = ".element";
const typed = new Typed( elem, {
        strings: ["Game", "Graphic"],
        typeSpeed: 100,
        backSpeed: 60,
        loop: true
    });
} else {
  console.log('You are on the server')
}                                               Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Comment: can you show where you insert the code? which line? s it inside the component or page or outside?

Comment: It was inside the default function before return () but now I have deleted the whole project and started with a fresh one